# How to fix the encoding problem produced by ANTLR4 in the parser generated?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, antlr4

I use an error alternative with a message in my grammar. The problem is that when the parser is generated, the message has encoding problems. How can I fix that?

This is what I put in my grammar :

```
{notifyErrorListeners("À corriger – l'expression ne correspond pas au type de l'attribut");}
```

And this is what the generated parser have :

```
notifyErrorListeners("ï¿½ corriger ï¿½ l'expression ne correspond pas au type de l'attribut");
```

Comment: what is the exact nature of the problem that you are facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using the latest ANTLR4 version (4.7.2) does this, try using the Unicode escapes for these characters:

```
{notifyErrorListeners("\u0192 corriger \u2013 l'expression ne correspond pas au type de l'attribut");}
```

If using an older version than 4.7.2, try upgrading first.

Comment: I did what you say, but it still now working. The generated parser keep the Unicode, it don't replace with the characters.

Comment: @talohsa sure, the escapes will remain, but when that string is printed to a console, or written to a file, you should get to see the actual characters.